# jQuery/Javascript - Limiting user input to a certain number of elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to limit the number of items a user can select to 4.

The items are all image/links, when the user clicks on an image it toggles the selected class and adds the element to an array of selected item values. If the user clicks on a 5th item it should drop the oldest item off the list. User should not be able to select the same item multiple times (filling the list with same item 4 times).

I believe it is the last part that is breaking my code (user can keep clicking on the same item and the array will get filled with the same selection 4 times.

```
  var selectList = [];
  $('.selectable').on('click', function () {
     $(this).toggleClass('selected');
     if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) { 
         selectList.push(this.dataset.fn);
        } else { 
         var index = selectList.indexOf(this.dataset.fn);
         if (index > -1) {selectList.splice(index, 1);}
        }
    if (selectList.length > 4) {
     $('a[data-fn=' + selectList[0] + ']').removeClass('selected');
      selectList.shift();
    }
 });
```

This breaks if i keep selecting the same image... Has to be an easier way!

Comment: Your code is working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/bortao/o16sacyL/

Comment: Maybe you are using jquery ui selectable but with your code you just don't need it

Comment: jQuery is forbidden in 2020 and beyond!

Answer (score 1):

**html**

```
<div class="item">1</div>
<div class="item">2</div>
<div class="item">3</div>
<div class="item">4</div>
<div class="item">5</div>
<div class="item">6</div>
```

**js**

```
const list = [];
const maxLen = 4

document.querySelectorAll('.item').forEach(el => {
  const klass = 'selected';
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const classes = el.classList;
    classes.toggle(klass);

    if (!classes.contains(klass)) {
      // item is unselected

      // remove item
      list.splice(list.indexOf(el), 1);      
    } else {
      if (list.length >= maxLen) {
        // remove oldest item
        const removed = list.shift();
        removed.classList.remove(klass);
      }

      // add new item
      list.push(el)
    }
  })
})
```